# Share Image not working in Windows 8.1 Universal App

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am writing a **Windows 8.1 Universal App**. Images are loaded from **server** into **GridView**. On Clicking on a GridViewItem (Image), it should share that image to WhatsApp,etc.

On Clicking GridViewItem, **ShareSticker** method executes:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView().DataRequested += OnShareDataRequested;
}

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView().DataRequested -= OnShareDataRequested;
}



        List<IStorageItem> storageItemsObject = new List<IStorageItem>();

StorageFile StorageFileObject;

private async void ShareSticker(string productID, string ProductServerURL, string ProductName)
    {
        try
        {
            StorageFolder StorageFolderObject = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync(LocalCache, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            if (StorageFolderObject != null)
            {
                string FileNameSaved = productID;
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(ProductServerURL);
                FileNameSaved = FileNameSaved + extension;
                StorageFileObject = null;
                StorageFileObject = await StorageFolderObject.CreateFileAsync(FileNameSaved, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                IRandomAccessStream StorageFileObjectStream = await StorageFileObject.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

                HttpClient HttpClientObject = new HttpClient();

                HttpClientObject.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)");
                Uri UriObject = new Uri(ProductServerURL);
                HttpResponseMessage HttpResponseMessageObject = await HttpClientObject.GetAsync(UriObject);
                HttpResponseMessageObject.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                IBuffer ResponseBuffer = await HttpResponseMessageObject.Content.ReadAsBufferAsync();
                DataWriter DataWriterObject;
                IOutputStream StorageFileObjectOutputStream;

                using (StorageFileObjectOutputStream = StorageFileObjectStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
                {
                    DataWriterObject = new DataWriter(StorageFileObjectOutputStream);
                    DataWriterObject.WriteBuffer(ResponseBuffer);

                    await DataWriterObject.StoreAsync();
                    await StorageFileObjectOutputStream.FlushAsync();
                }

                storageItemsObject.Clear();
                storageItemsObject.Add(StorageFileObject);

                DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();

            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

private void OnShareDataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs _dataRequestedEventArgs)
{
    DataRequest request = _dataRequestedEventArgs.Request;
    request.Data.Properties.Title = "KeyTreat Sticker";
    request.Data.Properties.Description = "KeyTreat Sticker: " + StickerName;

    // Because we are making async calls in the DataRequested event handler,
    // we need to get the deferral first.
    DataRequestDeferral deferral = request.GetDeferral();

    // Make sure we always call Complete on the deferral.
    try
    { 
            request.Data.SetStorageItems(storageItemsObject);
            #if WINDOWS_APP
            request.Data.Properties.Thumbnail = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromFile(StorageFileObject);
            request.Data.SetBitmap(RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromFile(StorageFileObject));
            #endif

    }
    finally
    {
            deferral.Complete();
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM:**
On clicking the image, it shows  "**PREPARING CONTENT TO SHARE**" for 1 second and nothing happens.

Comment: No effect after removing it.

Comment: I was reading: http://blog.thomaslebrun.net/2014/08/windows-phone-sharing-images-on-windows-phone-8-1-winrt-apps/#.VbCuua5tUgk

Comment: While I was testing that on an Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT) application, I found that if you want to share an image, you’ll need to share the StorageFile instead. Well, in fact, if you try to share, you’ll see that it’s working except that the image is not displayed/used. This is due to the fact that when an application implement the Share contract (in receive mode), it needs to indicate which file format it’s able to manage: uris, bitmap, file, text, etc. The native Windows Phone’s apps does not seems to manage the Bitmap format of the Share contract